# Django Application structure

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django, and there is one think bugging me, what is the "correct" way to build my project structure? Is it better to have multiples apps, each one handling a resource or some apps handling parts of my application?

Eg: when i run

```
python manage.py startapp brands
```

the app brands is responsible only for my brands resource (brand model, brand views, etc..)?

OR

each app can have more responsability like

```
python manage.py startapp products
```

then the products app will handle Brands, categories, products etc..?

Comment: In short: there is no correct way; there's only that way which makes the most sense for a particular project. Products, brands, categories are very closely related things and putting them in separate apps won't make much sense.

Comment: One way to think of it might be by audience.  You could have one app for customers to browse and buy products, and a separate app for managers to update product information and add/remove products.

Comment: I would base my decision on whether i would use an app that's already being created from someone else or if i would code it on my one. If it's lots of work and it seems that this feature is often reused i would create a new app otherwise just implement it all together.